# Look up the next highest value in another column with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns A and B.

```
 A          B
 20        100
 40        200
 60        300
 80        400
140        500
190        600
240        700
```

User inputs a value in a cell. I need to check the value input by the user against values in Column A and output the value in Column B corresponding to the nearest higher value in A.
ex. if user has input 90, the output should be 500. If the user inputs 41, the output should be 300.

Comment: You might need to use the `Lookup` function in Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way may be to insert `0` in `A2` (making space for it by shunting the rest down) and then applying `=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2)` (assuming value to be looked up is in `C2`). This would return `0` for 240 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do VLOOKUP.  Use INDEX-MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Return_value_range, MATCH(Lookup_value, Lookup_value_range, Match_type))
```

Return_value_range - The range that holds the return values

Lookup_value – The value you want to find in the lookup value array

Lookup_value_range – The range containing lookup values

Match_type – Exact (0), Nearest Greater Than (-1), or Nearest Less Than (1)

So in your example, your equation would look something like this:

```
=INDEX(B1:B7,MATCH(NUMBERYOUARELOOKINGFOR,A1:A7,-1))
```

The only caveat with this is that when you use -1 (nearest greater) your list needs to be in descending order.  Though, with crafty function use, this might be subverted.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for the LOOKUP function is:

> LOOKUP( value, lookup_range, [result_range] )

**value** is the value to search for in the lookup_range.

**lookup_range** is a single row or single column of data that is sorted in ascending order. The LOOKUP function searches for value in this range.

**result_range** is optional. It is a single row or single column of data that is the same size as the lookup_range. The LOOKUP function searches for the value in the lookup_range and returns the value from the same position in the result_range. If this parameter is omitted, the LOOKUP function will return the first column of data.

**Notes**

- If the LOOKUP function can not find an exact match, it chooses the largest value in the lookup_range that is less than or equal to the value.
- If the value is smaller than all of the values in the lookup_range, then the LOOKUP function will return #N/A.
- If the values in the LOOKUP_range are not sorted in ascending order, the LOOKUP function will return the incorrect value.

**The use of VLOOKUP**

> VLOOKUP( value, table_array, index_number, [not_exact_match] )

Adding the Range Lookup Argument

The Range_lookup argument is a logical value (TRUE or FALSE only) that indicates whether you want VLOOKUP to find an exact or an approximate match to the Lookup_value.

If **TRUE** or if this argument is omitted, VLOOKUP will use an approximate match if it cannot find an exact match to the Lookup_value. If an exact match is not found, VLOOKUP returns the next largest value that is less than the Lookup_value.

If **FALSE**, VLOOKUP will only use an exact match to the Lookup_value. If there are two or more values in the first column of Table_array that match the Lookup_value, the first value found is used. If an exact match is not found, a **#N/A error** is returned.

[image]

Comment: The LOOKUP function can work for this, but need to offset the `result_range` (or `result_vector`) to meet the requirements of the question. Assuming the input is in `C1` and the output is in `D1`, then the formula in `D1` should be `=LOOKUP(C1,A1:A7,B2:B7)`. The `result_range` starting from `B2` is important as the question wants a rounding up sort of mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was aware of the Lookup function. Only that the function VLOOKUP returns the next largest value that is less than the Lookup_value. I need the smallest value that is greater than the lookup_value.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` will not work for what you want, but if you use `LOOKUP` with the `result_range` offset by one row, it should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I will try out your suggestion. Thanks a lot Amer

Comment: Amer. It works. I have tried it out now and it works well. I had to add an IF statement for the row that was left out because of the offset.